# Write the crontab entry for printing the report file /usr/aa1/finacc/bsheet on first Monday of every month?

Tags: shell, unix

Any one suggest me how to run the cron job on first monday of every month?

Is it correct?

```
0 0 ? * 1#  /usr/aa1/finacc/bsheet
```

Comment: I assume you mean "first monday of every month", right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say:

```
0 0 1-7 * * [ "$(date +\%A)" == "Monday" ] && /usr/aa1/finacc/bsheet
```

for executing the command on the *first Monday* of a month (at midnight).

`1-7` would execute the command only on the first 7 seven days of a month.

`[ "$(date +\%A)" == "Monday" ]` checks if the day is a `Monday`.  Saying `&&` causes the command on it's right side to be executed only if the left side evaluates to true (which happens only on a Monday).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works fine. Can u please tell me what is the use of \ in \%A, can we use without \ aslo? i tried using without \, but it is not executed.

Comment: You need to escape the `%` in the command when using it in crontab.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 0 0 1-7 * 1 /usr/aa1/finacc/bsheet
```

The columns:
minute (0)
hour (0)
day of month  (any of 1-7)
month (any)
day of week (monday)